# Get UTC time without relying on OS time

Tags: java

Is it possible in java to get UTC time without relying on OS time settings?

For example in java 8 time api `Instant.now()` returns time in UTC. If I change system time in OS to 30 minutes ahead it will give me `UTC time + 30 minutes`.

Is there a clock that doesn't depend which OS settings is used, some kind of machine clock? if so, how to use it from java.

Comment: The only way that pops up in my mind is by pending the time from a server (which most likly gives a timestamp based on his OS time settings)

Comment: when one installs OS on the machine time settings is used from BIOS, some kind of machine clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get `System.currentTimeMillis()` this is the system/machine clock time for GMT+0. There is no additional truer time available on your machine.  You could ask a time service for the time available to it however it would have some error, and significant latency and you need to rely on it's accuracy.

The only other clock available is `System.nanoTime()` which on most machines is the number of nano seconds since the machine reset. It can't be altered by adding or subtracting 30 minutes but it is not relative to any standard time, nor does it correct for drift which can be in the tens of milli-second per day.

Comment: so without asking external service it's impossible?

Comment: @maks yes. There are two timers available but neither do what you want.

Comment: what about timer present in BIOS or similar software on the machine preinstalled by manufacturer(or configured in the store) aka "hardware clock"? When you install an OS it pulls time settings from there, at least I've observed it on my machine:)

Comment: @maks it does and when you correct the clock it is corrected also to avoid drift.